# javascript open a new window (maximized) with all toolbars

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

My initial code was just this.

`<a href="http://www.google.com.sg" target="_blank">test</a>`

Then I was complained that the new window was not maximized. They want it to be maximized.

So, now i call a javascript function on `onclicked` of `a` tag

Then I research on google how to open the maximized with all toolbars and so on.

This is the result of what I found and I tweaked it to get this far.

```
w=800 
h=600 
if (window.screen) { 
w = window.screen.availWidth; 
h = window.screen.availHeight; 
} 
window.open('http://www.google.com.sg','newwin','width='+w+',height='+h+',top=0,left=0,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes');
```

The above script will open a new window with all toolbar and so on but the screen size is the real screen size, hence it stretches up to window task bar.

I can try to minus some from height but I also found out that the button on top right are not really maximized.

Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: Yes, I have seen that and it is not my solution. Even my current code works better than that.

Comment: My current workaround is to minus the height.